# Devexpress AspxGridView Hide SelectCheckbox programmatically?

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I have a Devexpress Gridview with the SelectCheckbox column turned on, and all my operations based on this work just fine. I want to hide the checkbox for a row conditionally based on another column value in the grid.

Is this possible with the SelectCheckbox in the Command column, or will I have to create a template in a column and do a bit of a work-around? Either way, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Achieve this In Grid **Rowdatbound event** You have to do work around it ..Here I Give You Demo Code..

```
 foreach (GridViewDataColumn c in gridView.Columns)
            {

            checkbox chk=grid.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(grid.Columns("name_colum"), "nameCheckBox")
            if(Your Condition)
                 {chk.visble=false;}


             }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid this but I suppose its unavoidable in this instance.